# How do you say 'mind you' in Spanish?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática, estilo

***Ojo, este cuarto es no lugar para charlar.***

This room is not a place for talk.

Any alternatives for it?

Comment: Is "for talk" a good construction or would it be "for talking"? I know it's not a question related with the main topic, but I'm curious about it.

Comment: For talk is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé en el contexto que preguntas como lo usaría ya que no lo tienes puesto en la frase en inglés, pero yo "Mind you" lo traduciría como "Te/Os importaría...". En este caso podría ser algo como:

> Os importaría guardar silencio, esta habitación no es lugar para
>   charlar.

Answer (score 3):

The correct order of the words would be:

> Este cuarto no es un lugar para charlar.

In Spanish, the negative particle 'not' going before the verb 'is', and I think that's a proper way to write the sentence with the correction described above.

Comment: Do you mean "Ojo" should be dropped or is it the proper translation for "mind you" here ?

Comment: @jlliagre You don't have to remove "Ojo", but the correct order of the sentence is this one.

Answer (score 1):

My alternative:

> Este cuarto no es lugar para charlas.

It's the most common form when someone wants to scold to a child, for example.